# How to reshape image array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

currently I'm working on a neural network that can classify the numbers in the Street View House Number dataset (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/). For now, I'm just trying to do it on the second format, the one similar to the MNIST dataset.

The problem I've encountered is that the shapes of the train and test arrays of examples are (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS, EXAMPLES) rather than (EXAMPLES, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS).

Is there a simple way to reshape the array to what I want without using many nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the object you are trying to reshape is a `Tensor` or `numpy.ndarray`.

If it is a `numpy.ndarray`, you can use `np.transpose`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((299, 299, 3, 50))
print(a.shape)  # (299, 299, 3, 50) H x W x C x M
b = np.transpose(a, [3, 0, 1, 2])
print(b.shape)  # (50, 299, 299, 3)
```

If it is a `Tensor`, You can use `tf.transpose` to change the order of the dimension in exactly the same way as `np.transpose`. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros((299, 299, 3, 50), dtype=tf.int32)
print(a.shape.as_list())  # [299, 299, 3, 50]
b = tf.transpose(a, [3, 0, 1, 2])
print(b.shape.as_list())  # [50, 299, 299, 3]
```